# I wish to create a forum that has a graph or some type of visual aid that shows how many members the forum has?

Tags: html, graph, forum, mybb

I wish to create a forum that has a graph or some type of visual aid that shows how many members the forum has?

What kind of platform/service should I be using to create an interactive graph that shows the total number of members in a forum such as MyBB.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [plotly's javascript library](https://plotly.com/javascript/getting-started/) to create the graph itself. You would be able to do most of your work in MyBB templates.

You would just need to write your own [MyBB plugin](https://docs.mybb.com/1.8/development/plugins/) to write the info you want graphed into the javascript.

So for example you'd have a MyBB template that looked like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');
    Plotly.newPlot( TESTER, [{
    x: {$xvals},
    y: {$yvals} }], {
    margin: { t: 0 } } );
</script>
```

And in your plugin, you'd have some php code that sets those values:

```php
$xvals = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]";
$yvals = "[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]";
```

prior to evaluating your template.